# Viewing class definition of built-in classes in Python like Symbol

Tags: python, class, sympy

I am very new to Python (switching from Matlab) and I am currently working with the SymPy package. I realised that I can calculate the derivate of a function with `f.diff(x)`, even when I have not imported the `diff` function. So, basically `f.diff(x)` works but `diff(f,x)` returns an error.

```py
from sympy import symbols
x = symbols('x')
f = x**2 + 1
f.diff(x)
```

The reason that I could think of was that `diff` is actually defined as a method attribute for the class `Symbol` and thus, `f.diff(x)` works as long as `x` is of `Symbol` type and `f` has been defined using `x`. Is there a way to somehow view the `Symbol` class definition in order to verify that a `diff` method attribute actually exists?

Comment: A hacky way to view all methods of an object is to do the dir(f) method

Comment: Thanks Alexis! That allowed me to confirm what I actually wanted to.

Comment: In general reading the documentation is also important, I'll be honest that the sympy documentation confuses me greatly (I haven't really used it). But in general documentation will cover all methods/attributes and their interactions.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason that I could think of was that `diff` is actually defined as a method attribute for the class `Symbol` and thus, `f.diff(x)` works as long as `x` is of `Symbol` type and `f` has been defined using `x`.

This is mostly correct (corrections below).

In contrast to Matlab, Python uses namespaces. This means that you only have very basic functions, classes, etc. available by default and everything else needs to be imported into the main namespace or is only available with a “prefix” specifying the namespace. What you gain from this is that you avoid name clashes and it’s easy to trace from which module a function is coming. For instance, in your example, the reader can see that `symbols` was imported from the `sympy` module (into the main namespace). This module also has a `diff` function (not the method) that you could use after importing with `from sympy import diff`.

In this sense, each object comes along with its own namespace, which is for most practical purposes determined by its class¹.
Functions in this namespace are called *methods* and (usually) do something on the object itself or using the specifics of the object itself.

Now, for the promised corrections or clarifications:
It is `f`’s class which is relevant here, not `x`’s.
You can see the class of `f` with `type(f)` and it is `Add` (residing in `sympy.core.add`).
This is because it is primarily a sum (of `x**2` and `1`).
More importantly, `Add` is a subclass of `Expr` (expression), which is the parent class for all SymPy expressions.
For example, the class `Symbol` is also a subclass of `Expr`.
(You can see this with `type(f).mro()`.)
And this is the important thing here: All SymPy expressions have the `diff` method.

It is actually not relevant that the argument of `f.diff` is a `Symbol` or `Expr`.
It only needs to be something that SymPy can reasonably interpret as one.
For example `f.diff("x")` also works, because SymPy can translate the string `"x"` to a Symbol that is equivalent to your `x`.

> Is there a way to somehow view the `Symbol` class definition in order to verify that a `diff` method attribute actually exists?

Yes. The easiest way is the basic Python function `dir`, which returns a list of all attributes (everything accessible by the `.` operator) of an object. Typically, most of these are methods. In you case, you can just call `dir(f)`. Note that this lists also contains quite some attributes starting with `_`, which indicates that they are not designated for user consumption. In any reasonable programming environment (IDE, IPython, Jupyter), this list is also shown to you when you use tab completion (<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

**However**, while learning about a class by going through all its methods is usually a good approach, for SymPy expressions this is not feasible.
There is a lot of things somebody could want to do with these expressions, but you will only ever use a fraction of them.
Instead, you can either guess the name of the method and thus narrow down your search considerable.
For example, you can guess that the method for differentiation starts with a *d* (be it for *differentiate* or *derivative*), and here the tab completion (<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>) only gives you four results instead of three hundred.
Another approach is that you start searching the documentation (or the Internet in general) with what your operation of interest (here differentiating) instead of your the object of your operation (here, SymPy expressions, i.e., instances of `Expr`). After all SymPy is all about the latter, so that is kind of a given.

Finally, normally there is a documentation of a class featuring all its methods.
For `Expr`, this is [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.expr).
Unfortunately, in case of `Expr` the documentation is not exhaustive, e.g., it lacks the `diff` method.
While this is not ideal, it is somewhat understandable given the amount of methods as well as the duality of methods and functions of SymPy: For most methods of `Expr`, an analogous function can be directly imported from `sympy`.

---

¹ You can also just add stuff there (`symbols.wrzlprmft = "foo"`), but that’s a pretty advanced and rare usage. Also some classes are made to block this, e.g., you cannot do `f.wrzlprmft = "foo"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wrzlprmft for this very detailed and clear explanation! It helps me understand all this much better now!

Comment: @GauravMalik: You’re welcome. Please note that if this answer solved your problem, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. Otherwise, please tell me what is missing.